# Recursive function - how is the tally stored in this factorial solution?

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the following function, which returns the factorial of a number, how is the tall of the numbers stored when the function is recursively called.

```
function factorialize(num) {
    if (num < 3) {
        return num;
    }
    return num * factorialize(num - 1);
}
factorialize(5);
```

I get that this is working backwards to achieve the factoral of 5, which is obtained by multiplying all positive numbers up to the passed number:

> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 obtains the result

I am confused as to how the result of each multiplication is stored or tallied to continually build towards the result of 120.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: http://mooreccac.com/kcppdoc/Recursion.htm

Comment: it runs like this, but w/shorter code: `function m(a,b){return a*b;}  m(1,m(2,m(3,m(4,5))));` hopefully you can see the nesting pattern in that simple hard-coded example, but in a recursive function, you can use `return` on another call instead of nesting invocations. either way, the output is `120`

Comment: Thanks guys, that explains it really well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is doing the check, and then calling itself. When it calls itself again, it passes in the result of a calculation.

So, every time `factorialize(num - 1);` is called, `num` will be the result of the previous call, and the calculation will remove 1 from that value and pass that new value in.

Step through is like this:

- Initial call is `factorialize(5)`, which calls the function with a parameter of 5.
- The function checks if `5` is less than 3 (it isn't), and if not, calls itself again. The parameter this time is the original parameter minus 1 - so `4`
- Next time round, it's checking if 4 is less than 3. If not, call itself again for 4 minus 1 - `3`
- This continues until the parameter passed in is less than 3